# TSQL query parser in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing

I would like to have something like a procedure that takes a query definition as input and output a set of tables containing the individual elements of the query.

### Searching the internet for this yields me numerous results in various programming languages, but not in tsql itself. Is there such a resource around?

An example in order to illustrate what I mean by parser:

Input example (any query, really:)

```
'select t1.col1,t2.col2
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2.col2
        on t1.t2ref=t2.key'
```

The output, of course, will be a multitude of data. I mentioned tables, but it could be in any form eg an xml. Here is a *VERY SIMPLISTIC* and arbitrary example of decomposition for the query above:

```
tables_used:
+----+-----------+--------+------------+
| id | object_id |  name  | alias used |
+----+-----------+--------+------------+
|  1 |  43252345 | table1 | t1         |
|  2 |   6542625 | table2 | t2         |
+----+-----------+--------+------------+

columns_used:
+----------+-------------+
| table_id | column name |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | col1        |
|        1 | t2ref       |
|        2 | key         |
|        2 | col2        |
+----------+-------------+

joins_used:
+-----+-----+-------+-----------------+
| tb1 | tb2 | type  |       on        |
+-----+-----+-------+-----------------+
|   1 |   2 | inner | t1.t2ref=t2.key |
+-----+-----+-------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `query definition`.

Comment: Can you show example input and output?

Comment: I will prepare an example to illustrate the question better.

Comment: SQL's a relational database so it's pretty bad at parsing strings. I'd be inclined to create a CLR stored procedure that does the parsing for you using Entity Framework's parser or even ANTLR.

Comment: I do not have priviledges to use CLR at this project. I was hoping some tool will be around since, at the end of the day, the server does parse the queries in order to run them...

Comment: Even if you somehow had the parser already built, shoehorning the output of parsing an arbitrarily complex query into a set of tables like you are envisioning here in a meaningful way would be very difficult, I think.

Comment: I wouldn't dream of doing this in TSQL. Even if you succeed (which is highly unlikely), you'll end up with a long, cumbersome, unreadable and unmaintainable code.

Comment: I fully understand the enormity of the task - and that's why I am indeed not "dreaming" of doing it - but it would be very nice if it was out there alreaady.

Comment: It might be possible to shred the XML from a query plan into something like this but it would be a massive undertaking. Arguably a query plan is already what you're asking for as it will list all data sources and how they are joined together, just not in the format you're asking for.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis No, I do not think you understand the enormity of your goal. The idea of "elements of a query" is very vague - far too vague to begin to implement. Lastly, suggestions for "was out there already" are off-topic.

Comment: There is a `TSqlParser` in .NET, and if you imported it in a CLR assembly you could call it from T-SQL -- but of course you do need permission for that. Even so I don't think there's much practical use for this -- in most cases you either want execution plans, or you can content yourself with the results of `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`. Client code that has an actual need for parsing would be much better off doing it on the client side than trying to use the results of T-SQL (which can only cough up tables, not trees). Writing a T-SQL parser in T-SQL is, of course, madness.

Comment: Having `object_id` implies more than just parsing, i.e. syntactic analysis. You also want binding to objects in an existing database and the attendant semantic analysis?